# Cannot crawl SharePoint 2013 site in SharePoint 2010 search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, sharepoint-online, crawling, sharepoint-search

I created a content source under search service application and configured the Sharepoint 2013 server URL (http://[2013servername](http://snmanivannan.com)/) for crawling.

Once the full crawling completed, I checked the search results it says *We did not find any results for server.*

Checked the Crawl log and find there is a TOP LEVEL ERROR as below

> Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access
>   Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl
>   this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint
>   repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read"
>   permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled. ( Error
>   from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode Unauthorized The request failed
>   with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized. )

Googled for this issue and tried disabling *DisableLoopbackCheck* but still doesnt work.

Any solution for searching SharePoint 2013 contents in 2010 site ?

Notes

- Able to ping 2013 from 2010 Machine
- Able to visit the 2013 site from 2010 Machine
- Both servers has the same admin user account
- Both are in different farms
- In 2013, search is working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set the domain name ADMINISTRATOR account (i.e *DOMAINNAME\Administrator*) in Search Crawl Account as **FULL READ**. Performed a FULL CRAWL in 2010 and tat works. Now I can access SharePoint 2013 content from SharePoint 2010 site.

But I'm not sure why I need to provide **FULL READ** access to the domain ADMINISTRATOR, when i used SP-ADMIN as the SEARCH CRAWL account. Anyway I got the case resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the site as the default crawl account? Usually you would set up a Policy on the Web application for full read for the account. Sounds like just permissions. (BTW, you should not use DisableLoopbackCheck in production.)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I used the domain SP-Admin account to crawl. I gave FULL READ permission in the Search Crawl Account for the SP-Admin. Noted on LoopbackCheck & reverted back :)

Comment: Did this resolve the issue? It is usually a bad idea to use the admin account for crawling as it has too much access and you will find unpublished items in your search results.